# How to use intellisense from monaco.d.ts

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

How can I include `monaco.d.ts` so that I can use intellisense when working with the `monaco-editor` package?

I have started with this package in a JavaScript based project. All is working fine. Now, I'm gradually migrating over to TypeScript. But VSCode always shows that classes/functions/... that are provided by this extension cannot be found. For example `CompletionItems`.

Using SO, I found that you can include `monaco.d.ts` in the `tsconfig.json` file like so:

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "src",
    "./node_modules/monaco-editor/monaco.d.ts"
  ],
  ...
  "files": ["./node_modules/monaco-editor/monaco.d.ts"]
  ...
}
```

But this also doesn't work. (Tried to restart VS Code as well)

So the general question is: How can I include any `d.ts` file so that intellisense recognises the types defined in there? Or more specifically: How can I do this for the `monaco.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

The tsconfig.json file serves as configuration for the typescript compiler. It won't add any feature to Monaco. Instead use `languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLiblanguages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib` to add the typings. Instead of `javascriptDefaults` you can also use `typescriptDefaults`, if you are going to use Typescript code in the Monaco editor. In my React Monaco editor component I added a simple method to allow other parts of the app to add their typings to Monaco:

```js
    public static addTypings(typings: string, source: string): void {
        languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typings, source);
        languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typings, source);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I might have given an unclear question here. I'm not looking for intellisense in the Monaco Editor that is included in my app. I want to have intellisense for teh npm package monaco-editor while developing my app in vscode. (not sure if this makes sense :D)

Comment: But that should work out of the box. The npm package comes with typings. Check, for instance: node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts. Nothing extra should be required to make this work for you.

Comment: That’s what I thought as well. But as this is my first TS project, I thought there is maybe some setup step required. Strange. Thanks.